# Crashlytics dysm size through Fabric for ios

Tags: ios, crashlytics, debug-symbols, twitter-fabric, dsym

We are at the final stage of releasing an app to the App Store and found that the dysm for our archive build is ~40 MB, we were wondering if there was a way to reduce this or if that kind of size is expected for builds?

Comment: Doesn't seem like an unreasonable size.